# Cura 5.4.0 Added "Print as support" Cylinder adds support to regions where there is no model. How to limit support to those areas that need it?

Tags: ultimaker-cura, support-structures

I added a cylinder object to my model and changed the object type from normal to "Print as support."  After slicing, the cylinder appears as support but this support exists in areas where there is no normal model (it's just supporting air).

This article [How to Add Manual Support in Cura](https://www.instructables.com/How-to-Add-Manual-Support-in-Cura/) states:

> Cura offers a selection to "print as support". That will print the
> whole cube as support. We just want the area under the leg within the
> cube. So choose that setting from the drop down menu.

The article doesn't clearly state what that setting is and Cura 5.4.0 has no drop down menu.  How do I get the support associated with this print-as-support cylinder to be generated for only those areas that are below the normal model?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Working with manual supports like the one you added, you are fully manual, no automatic options to adjust them - they are intended to be used in situations where the automation has already failed after all.

So - select (click in the work area) the support, and use scale, translate, rotate options to make it the size that does what you want and little-to-no more. Unchecking even scaling will allow you to smoosh it into a thin ellipse which you can place under suspended edges. You can even tilt it to act as a makeshift tree support, just make it taller than needed and sink a part under the plate so the adhesion layer is wide enough. You can also overlap it in significant part with the printed object - Cura will correctly trim around the skin of the object, making sure it's supported and not permanently glued into the support.